# Stopping IntentService by clicking Notification

Tags: android

I'm doing some background work in an IntentService and trying to make it stop by clicking a notification. For stopping the work I have a static method, that sets a flag.

```
public static void stopService() {
    if (task != null) {
        task.setCancelFlag(true);
    }
}
```

The notification has a `PendingIntent`, that sends a Broadcast to a Receiver, that attempts to stop the service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setAction(AlarmReceiver.STOP_SERVICE);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,
                intent, 0);

notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

The Receiver calls the `stopService()` method when it receives a broadcast.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(STOP_SERVICE)) {
    UpdateCheckService.stopService();
}
```

Strangely enough, the `stopService()` method is not called properly. If I try to log it, the part with the flag setting is not executed. Even if I set a breakpoint on the Receiver and try to debug it, it doesn't work.

However, if I call the same method from an `Activity` by clicking a button, everything works as intended.

Does somebody know, where this strange behavior comes from?

Comment: Yes, it's a static reference to an AsyncTask.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. It appears that you are starting an AsyncTask from your IntentService and then wanting that to stop? IntentService starts a new thread for onHandleIntent so by starting an AsyncTask you lose the entire benefit of using an IntentService.

Comment: UpdateCheckService.stopService(false, context); does not call .stopService()

Comment: I updated the code snipped. The real code signatures differ a bit, but that's not the point. Regarding the AsyncTask: I know it sounds strange, but for code redundancy reasons I just call the 'doInBackground' method of the AsyncTask, so no extra thread is created. The "real" asynchronous part is used somewhere else in the code.

Comment: When you debug it is task == null?

Comment: The problem is, I can not debug it. When I set a breakpoint, nothing happens. (In case of the notification thing, everything works fine, when called from an Activity).

Comment: So you have not verified that the Receiver ever receives the broadcast?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3705/discussion-between-mike-dg-and-cypressious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mystery is solved: My BroadcastReceiver had the remote process flag set, which I copied from some tutorial on the web without too much thinking. Removing this tag made everything work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using the intent of IntentService to create the PendingIntent

In **onHandleIntent** I invoke the notification :

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent pStopSelf = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Then I added the stop button and call my notification (insert this line on NotificationCompat.Builder):

```
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp, "Stop", pStopSelf)
```

Clicking the stop on the notification will not trigger onHandleIntent, but invoke `onStartCommand`. Here you can check if the intent contains the flag we set to stop the service.

```
private boolean shouldStop = false;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getFlags() == PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stop pressed");
        stopSelf();
        shouldStop = true;
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

`stopSelf()` stops any intents containing work requests to do more work in the intent service to restart the service. But it *does not stop* the service itself.

To stop the service from continuing to execute, use the boolean previously set to check if the work should continue like this in `onHandleIntent()`

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //Invoke notification

    doStuff();
}

private void doStuff() {
    // do something 

    // check the condition
    if (shouldContinue == false) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Use the boolean to check in between the code to check if service should stop and return from the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the IntentService class for your case. IntentService use a queue to process one Intent at a time. Just create your own class that extend Service as the example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#ExtendingService). 
Then handle the stop request as you did to stop the worker thread.

Comment: I know, this is a possibility, but I would like to stick to IntentService. Apart from that, the behavior, as I described it, is quiet strange, isn't it?